# Increase mysql db allotment on Linux / Cpanel

Tags: apache, cpanel

Hi I have root ssh access to a Linux server that has Cpanel installed. Currently each host account can only have 1 Mysql database. Where can I increase this setting so users can create more than 1 Mysql database via Cpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to WHM, login as user root and go to ***Home*** -> ***Account Functions*** -> ***Modify an Account*** , select the cPanel account you want to modify and increase the value of ***SQL Databases*** as per your needs.